# Pandas DataFrame groupby a timestamp frequency with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex (timestamp, dgg) like so:

```
In [1]: df.head()
Out[1]: 
                   smos_vwc   map_vwc
timestamp  dgg                       
2015-03-31 233862  0.195203  0.315370
           233348  0.321409  0.271887
           233349  0.272508  0.275955
           233350  0.249663  0.279324
           232833  0.269949  0.266547
```

The timestamps go on for many days. I'd like to group this data by month and dgg, but I'm not sure a good way to go about it. If I were grouping by month with a DataFrame with a normal index, I could do `df.groupby(df.index.month)` (or use `pd.TimeGrouper`), but a MultiIndex doesn't have the DatetimeIndex attributes.

And just to throw it out there, if I don't care to keep around dgg, I can `df.reset_index(level='dgg').groupby(df.reset_index(level='dgg').index.month)`, but then I lose dgg grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to group by the month, and not the year-month (e.g., 2012-03 and 2013-03 are in the same group), you could do this:

- Reset your index to that `dgg` and `timestamp` become regular columns
- the compute  month into it's own column,
- then group by `dgg` and `month`.

That looks like this:

```
result = (
    df.reset_index()
      .assign(month=lambda x: x['timestamp'].dt.month)
      .grouby(by=['dgg', 'month'])
      .<apply/agg/transform/filter>(...)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Kicking myself for not thinking to reset both indexes and go from there :) Fortunately, I don't have to worry about different years right now, but I think it's pretty clear how to do it if (when) it becomes necessary.